# How to display all anime that belongs to a certain season? Really hard to explain please read

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a season model and a anime model. I have it set so i have spring, summer, fall and winter through season. Each anime will belong to spring, summer, fall or winter. In my home page i want to display a section for all the seasons showing the anime that it belongs to. I can display the name of all the seasons and i can make all the anime show in localhost:3000/seasons/spring if it belongs to spring. I cant figure out how to display the anime that belongs to each season(spring, summer, fall, winter) in the home page.

This is how my anime in db looks like

```
create_table "animes", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.string   "type_of"
 t.integer  "episodes"
 t.string   "status"
 t.date     "started_at"
 t.date     "ended_at"
 t.string   "producers"
 t.string   "duration"
 t.string   "rating"
 t.text     "description"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.string   "slug"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "image_file_name"
 t.string   "image_content_type"
 t.integer  "image_file_size"
 t.datetime "image_updated_at"
 t.string   "source_name"
 t.string   "source_link"
 t.string   "crunchyroll"
 t.integer  "season_id"
 t.integer  "genre_id"
 t.integer  "studio_id"
 t.string   "header_file_name"
 t.string   "header_content_type"
 t.integer  "header_file_size"
 t.datetime "header_updated_at"
end
```

This is how my season table looks like

```
 create_table "seasons", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "slug"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
 end
```

Anime Model

```
class Anime < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :season
end
```

Season model

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :animes
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here, depending on what you want to show

#### simple list with attributes

```
  <% Anime.includes(:season).each do |anime| %>
    <p><%= anime.title %> -- <%= anime.season.name %></p>
  <% end %>
```

#### grouped by season

```
<% Season.scoped.each do |season| %>
  <h3><%= season.name %></h3>
  <% season.animes.each do |anime| %>
    <p><%= anime.title %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `Season.each` raise `undefined method 'each' for Season`.